# Bigrams of words from a list of sentences in a paragraph,R

Tags: r

I am doing bigram tokenization of words in R. I am getting it only for a complete paragraph. I have divided paragraph into single sentence. Now I need to create a list of words for each of these sentences.

Input:

```
   [1] "The dog chased a cat."
   [2] "The cat climbed a tree"
```

Output:

```
    [1] [1] "The" "dog"
        [2] "chased" "the"
        [3] "cat".....

    [2] [1] "The" "cat"
        [2] "climbed" "the"
```

I need R code for this...
I have tried it using with the following code
:

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=2,max=2))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package, but you could use `stringi::stri_extract_all_words` to extract all the words from a sentence and return them in list form.

Comment: The expected output.is not clear. To transform your sentences to words:  strsplit(xx," ") should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need the tm package in combination with your tokenizer.

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
text <- c("The dog chased a cat.", "The cat climbed a tree")


mycorp <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=2,max=2))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mycorp, control=list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
findFreqTerms(tdm)
[1] "a cat"       "a tree"      "cat climbed" "chased a"    "climbed a"   "dog chased"  "the cat"     "the dog"
```

Comment: I need list of words for each sentence in a paragraph. Should I need to use for loop?

Comment: It all depends on how your data is stored and how you want to report your words per sentence. Read the vignettes of the tm or qdap package. There are examples how to set up a corpus if that is the route you want to take.